# Show that the quotient of a connected graph by the action of a group is a connected graph.

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

Could someone give me a suggestion to solve this problem?

Show that the quotient of a connected graph by the action of a group is a connected graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any two elements in the quotient, these are represented by some elements $a, b$ in the original graph.  The original graph is connected so take a path of edges from $a$ to $b$.  Show that this path in the original graph corresponds to a path of edges in the quotient between the original two vertices.